# Google Play is installing ARM apps in my x86 device

Tags: google-play-store, x86-processors

I have an x86 Android tablet, i had no issue with it until i did a factory reset. After the reset, i noticed Chrome didn't want to launch at all (it crashed on startup).

I ran logcat and concluded the crash was related to `libhoudini.so`, which is the ARM support library for x86 devices. I extracted the APK from the device and realized it only had ARM native libraries in it. I did the same with other apps installed from the Play Store that i knew had native libraries and the result was the same, only ARM versions of the apps were getting installed. Again, this didn't happen before the factory reset.

I manually downloaded and installed an x86 version of Chrome and it ran just fine, but does anybody know why is Google Play only downloading ARM versions of the apps? and is there a way to fix it? Google Chrome wasn't the only app that gave me issues, other apps with ARM libraries usually crash as well (not at startup, but they do occasionally crash without reason)